# I need to use a selector on hover and a variable set outside hover to find a specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is going to be difficult for me to explain, so I'll do my best. Heres this code:

```
$('#navibar a').hover(function(){
    var position = $(this).position(); 
    var width = $(this).width();
    $('#underliner').css({'width': '' + width + '','left': position.left});
    //$('#underliner').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
    $('#underliner').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 30).show();
}, function () {
    var homePos = $(this).find(attr(activePageHref)).position();
    var homeWidth = $(this).find(attr(activePageHref)).width();
    //$('#underliner').css({'width': '' + homeWidth + '','left': homePos.left});
    //$('#underliner').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
    //$('#underliner').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 30).show();
    alert(activePageHref);
});
```

activePageHref is set outside this as the page that has been clicked on. On the alert, it is showing correctly (for examples, lets just say its value is "home". I need to somehow set the #underliner.css position and width to the page link in the navigation that is selected on hover out, so is there a way to "find" other 'a's and use them? Hopefully in the code it's obvious what I was trying to do. This is my markup:

```
<ul id="navibar">
            <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="products">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="games">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="store">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="support">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="community">Community</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Also, I know the first block of code is BIG TIME wrong, that was just the last thing I did out of aggrevation and desperation before I decided to post on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute selector to find the link with the href as activePageHref

```
$('#navibar a').hover(function(){
    var position = $(this).position(); 
    var width = $(this).width();
    $('#underliner').css({'width': '' + width + '','left': position.left});
    //$('#underliner').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
    $('#underliner').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 30).show();
}, function () {
    var homePos = $(this).parents('#navibar').find('a[href="'+activePageHref+'"]').position();
    var homeWidth = $(this).parents('#navibar').find('a[href="'+activePageHref+'"]').width();
    //$('#underliner').css({'width': '' + homeWidth + '','left': homePos.left});
    //$('#underliner').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
    //$('#underliner').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 30).show();
    alert(activePageHref);
});
```

Comment: It's saying homePos is null, when I know for sure activePageHref is not by commenting everything out and using the alert. Uncommenting lines 3 and 5 of the hover out funciton.

Comment: I just realize that `this` is not `#navibar` see edit, I just replaced the lines in your code with the code to find the required elements.

Comment: I should have caught that too, still coming up null though. Also, just for anyone else that might come and look, you have a ' out of place after activePageHref.

Comment: @GrantKesslerJr I needed to use `.parents()` instead of `.parent()` since `#navibar` is an ancestor and not the parent.

Comment: Still null. I should have caught that myself too. xD

Comment: Still coming up null for me. Doesn't make sense, maybe I'm just too tired. I editted the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyyNH/1/) to show how I'm getting activePageHref. Again, if I alert activePageHref it says what I want, so I'm lost.

Comment: You use `activePageHref` before you set it , in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyyNH/2/) I set it after `$('#bodycontent').load('home.php');`

Comment: I do apologize, but I initialize it at the top of my jquery. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyyNH/3/) it is set initially before all this. That's why I'm getting the value 'home', but everything else is null and it makes no sense.

Comment: @GrantKesslerJr you change the value of `href` to `#` that's why its not being selected and returning null if only the current item has an href as # then use that as the selector `a[href="#"]` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyyNH/4/)

Comment: I apologize for my last post. I was extremely tired and really shouldn't have been messing with my site probably. You were correct though, and now it is working just fine. I appreciate your patience and help!

Answer (score 2):

First, you can the selected 'a' via something like `event.target`; 
Second, you add `activeClass` to the target;
Third, get the other a's by selector, such as `$("ul#navibar li a:not(.activeClass)")`
Here you will get those not active a's in a array, which you can traverse via `$.each`

May it will help you a bit.

Comment: I should have used classes instead a while ago probably, and am now trying to avoid it so I don't have to rewrite some stuff that already works.